# How could I use structure type in a function to calculate the time?

Tags: julia, julia-jump

one of the way to calculate time of running a main code is that we use main code as a function. but if the code includes a structure type this error will be happened.

```
using JuMP,CPLEX,Plots,CPUTime,DataStructures,StatsBase,Distributions

function NSG()
    #problem definition------------------------------------------------------------
    nvar=3;            # number of decision variables
    varmin=-4;       # lowerbound of variables
    varmax=4;        # upper bound of variables
    varsize=1:nvar;   # size of decision variables matrics
    nobj=length(MOP2(rand(Uniform(varmin,varmax),nvar))); # number of objective functions
    #-----NSGA-II parameters-------------------------------------------------------
    MaxIt=100;  #maximum iteration
    npop=50;  #population size
    pcrossover=0.7; #crossover percentage
    nc=2*round((pcrossover*npop)/2); #number of offsprings or parents
    pmutation=0.4;    #mutation percentage
    nm=round(pmutation*npop);    #number of mutants
    mu=0.02   #Mutation rate
    sigma=0.1*(varmax-varmin) #mutation step size

    #---intialization--------------------------------------------------------------
    struct individual
        position
        cost
        Rank
        Dominationset
        Dominatedcount
        Crowdingdostance
    end
    pop = [individual([],[],[],[],[],[])  for i in 1:npop]

    return pop
end
@time @CPUtime pop=NSG()


ERROR: error compiling nsga2: type definition not allowed inside a loca
l scope
```

this is MOP2 function

```
function MOP2(x)
    n=length(x);
    z1=1-exp(-sum((x-1/sqrt(n)).^2));
    z2=1-exp(-sum((x+1/sqrt(n)).^2));
    z=[z1;z2];
    return z
end
```

would you please help me how could I solve it? or how could I calculate time of a main code without putting the code in a function type.

thanks very much.

for solving the problem it could be useful.

my problem is solved as follow:

```
using JuMP,CPLEX,CPUTime

struct individual
        position
        cost
        Rank
        Dominationset
        Dominatedcount
        Crowdingdostance
    end

function NSG()
    #problem definition------------------------------------------------------------
    nvar=3;            # number of decision variables
    varmin=-4;       # lowerbound of variables
    varmax=4;        # upper bound of variables
    varsize=1:nvar;   # size of decision variables matrics
    nobj=length(MOP2(rand(Uniform(varmin,varmax),nvar))); # number of objective functions
    #-----NSGA-II parameters-------------------------------------------------------
    MaxIt=100;  #maximum iteration
    npop=50;  #population size
    pcrossover=0.7; #crossover percentage
    nc=2*round((pcrossover*npop)/2); #number of offsprings or parents
    pmutation=0.4;    #mutation percentage
    nm=round(pmutation*npop);    #number of mutants
    mu=0.02   #Mutation rate
    sigma=0.1*(varmax-varmin) #mutation step size

    #---intialization--------------------------------------------------------------

    pop = [individual([],[],[],[],[],[])  for i in 1:npop]

    return pop
end
@time @CPUtime pop=NSG()
```

Comment: Could you actually show a simplified reproducible code that does that? Also what are you using for timing a code?

Comment: After your edit, this is still not a **minimal**, reproducible example. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . Your question however, should be answered in my answer below as far as I can see it.

Comment: thanks. you are perfectly right. although it is a section of a code, it is reproduceable. when it is debugged, the bellow error was for structure type (`pop`).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stop the time some code needs without writing it as functions you can just use `begin` `end` blocks

```
@time begin 
    struct ms 
       a 
    end 
    B = ms(rand(10,10,10)) 
    ms_sum = sum(B.a)
end
```

Comment: Thanks very much. but how about CPUtime? How is it possible calculate it?

Comment: I don't see the problem, as far as I can see it, it works the same as regular `@time`, just put it in front of `begin`-`end` blocks.

Comment: sure it doesn't have problem for `time`. but for `CPUTime` ? is there any way to calculate that ?

Comment: I said `CPUtime` works the same as regular `@time` as far as I know. Did you even try it yourself? Just plug in the CPUTime above and it ll work.

Comment: I tried.  it doesn't work. It gives this error `UndefVarError: @CPUTime not defined`.

Comment: It does work. Look at your own code above. You have to import the CPUTime library and use the correct macro like you tried in your own code: `@CPUtime`

Comment: It will work if the structure definition take out of the function. I revised the question and change the code with CPUTime.